# WebRequest loading HTMLDocument coming back with all special characters for SSL site

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack

Pretty standard implementation of HttpWebRequest, whenever I pass a certain URL to get the html it comes back with nothing but special characters. An example of what comes back is below.

Now this site is SSL so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it but I've never had this problem before and I've used this with other SSL sites.

```
�


       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
            HtmlDocument hDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            using (StreamReader readURLContent = new StreamReader(data))
            {
                html = readURLContent.ReadToEnd();
                hDoc.LoadHtml(html);
            }
        }
```

I can't really find anything for this specific issue so I'm kind of lost if anybody could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Edit: here's an image of what it looks like since I can't copy paste it
[image]

Comment: Well, the response stream is still encoded. This is common. You have to decode it. You can read the header or `response.CharacterSet` to get the Encoding (`Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);`) and fallback to `Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");` if none is specified. Sometime, you have to extract the encoding from the meta-charset of the html page to match the one actually used.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the response is compressed. If you use a WebDebugger like Charles or Fiddler. You can see how the requests and structured and what data they contain - it makes it a lot easier to replicate the http requests later on when programming them. Try the following code.

```
try
{
    string webAddr = url;
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0";
    httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;


    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        doc.LoadHtml(responseText);
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

The code sets the encoding on the requsts. You an also set the encoding at the streamreader when reading the response. And automatic decompression is enabled.

Comment: The Stream looks like GZip compressed, but those "\u" unicode symbols shouldn't be there if it was just Gzipped. It seems to also be Unicode encoded. This shouldn't happen. It's strange that you get a Gzipped stream if no headers (i.e `HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate"`) specify that you are accepting it. Maybe the code the OP is showing is not all of it and something is configured the wrong way.